# Delete records from a DataTable on the basis of certain condition C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have one `DataTable` (dtProperty) with following columns:

> 1. PropertyId,
> 2. List item
> 3. RoomId,
> 4. RateId,
> 5. Roomsequence

I have 2 variables RoomCount and PID whose values are known for a particular combination of PropertyId,RoomId,RateId the Roomsequence should have all the values less then equal to RoomCount.

> If values of RoomCount is 3 and PID=10212 then for a partcular value of PropertyId,RoomId,RateId ::10212,2010,3101(in our case) RoomSequence should have values 1,2,3.

If any partcular combination of  PropertyId,RoomId,RateId does not satisfy the criteria then we

should dicard the row from the data table.

In the table listed below ,we will retain  only top 3 and last 3 rows

```
PropertyId  RoomID  RateID   RoomSequence
10212       2010    3101     1
10212       2010    3101     2
10212       2010    3101     3
10212       2011    3100     3
10212       2012    3101     1
10212       2012    3101     2
10212       2014    3101     1
10212       2014    3101     2
10212       2014    3101     3
```

Comment: So what is the question? Is RoomCount == RoomSequence? Poor quality questions do not attract many answers...

Comment: Dont you simply want to filter the Data not DELETE it? If so, you can use LINQ to sort the data

Answer (score 0):

```
    var filteredTable = (from row in dtRoom.AsEnumerable()
      where row.Field<int>("RoomSequence") <=
      GetRoomCount(row.Field<int>("PropertyId"), 
                   row.Field<int>("RoomId"), 
                   row.Field<int>("RateID"))
    select row); //ToDataTable()
```

This should get you a new datatable with data according to your room sequence filter.
Ofcourse you should return the RoomCount from inside the method `GetRoomCount` depeding on the 3 values.